# In a GLM, how do the dimensions of the linear predictor and the range of the link function always align?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, exponential-family

Let $\mathbf{\vec y}$ be the response vector.
Then, we can write the exponential family as :
$$
\large p(y;\boldsymbol{\eta})=h(y) \exp \left(\boldsymbol{\eta} \cdot \mathbf{T}(y)-A(\boldsymbol{\eta})\right)
$$
In the context of GLMs, $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ is both the natural parameter and the linear predictor given as :
$$
\boldsymbol{\eta} =\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{X}
$$
Where $\mathbf{\vec w}$ is the weight vector and $\mathbf{X}$ is the feature matrix.

We then write the hypothesis of the GLM as :
$$
\large \mathbf{h}_{\mathbf{\vec w}}(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{g}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\eta})
$$
Where $\mathbf{g}^{-1}$ is the inverse of link function called the mean function.

Now consider gamma regression, $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ is given as :

$$
\boldsymbol{\eta} = \begin{bmatrix} \eta _{1} \\ \eta _{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha - 1 \\ -\beta \end{bmatrix}
$$

Here, $\boldsymbol{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and if we are considering $m$ training examples and $n$ features, then $\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ .
Clearly, $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ and $\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{X}$ are not compatible and cannot be set equal.
Moreover, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function), the hypothesis of gamma regression is given as :
$$
\mathbf{h}_{\mathbf{\vec w}}(\mathbf{X}) = -\frac{1}{\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{X}}
$$

> My question is this : *how do we know that the dimensions of $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ and $\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{X}$ are compatible?*

> Follow-up question : how is the hypothesis of gamma regression derived if we cannot set $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ equal to $\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{X}$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the exact definition of gamma regression. The hypothesis of gamma regression is derived from the gamma distribution with a redundant scale parameter $\alpha$ .
What this means is that we don't consider $\alpha$ when equating the linear predictor to $\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf X$ .

More precisely, we set $\alpha = 1$ , which gives us $\eta_1 = 0$ .
By *definition*, we set $\eta_2 = \mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf X$ .

This gives :
$$
\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf X = - \beta \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\beta} = - \frac{1}{\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf X}
$$
Also note that the mean of the gramma distribution is $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ .
And since $\alpha = 1$ , the mean is equal to $\frac{1}{\beta}$ .
Thus, we can write :
$$
\mu = - \frac{1}{\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf X} = \mathbf{h}_{\mathbf{\vec w}}(\mathbf{X})
$$
This is how the gamma regression hypothesis is derived.
A similar process is followed when deriving the hypothesis of linear regression from the normal distribtuion, where we set the standard deviation to 1.
Conclusively, for most distributions that have non-scalar natural parameters, we typically select one parameter and equate it to the linear predictor.

Comment: With `gamlss` models you can have gamma regressio with separate linear predictors for mean and variance https://rdrr.io/cran/gamlss.dist/man/GA.html